# know if a specific word exist in Array?

Tags: php

i have an array and i want to know if it countains a specific word or not for exemple microsoft-iis 7.5 ?

```
Array
(
[0] => HTTP/1.1 302 Found
[1] => Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, no-transform
[2] => Pragma: no-cache
[3] => Content-Length: 340
[4] => Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
[5] => Expires: -1
[6] => Server:microsoft-iis 7.5
)
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to know whether the string exists, you could run stripos on the imploded string:

```
if (false !== stripos(implode("\n", $headers), "microsoft-iis"))
{
   // ...
}
```

(or strpos if you want case sensitivity).

Answer (score 1):

```
if(array_walk($array, function($str){ return strstr($str, 'microsoft-iss 7.5'); })){
    echo "array_matches";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$stack = Array(
          '0' => 'HTTP/1.1 302 Found',
          '1' => 'Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, no-transform',
          '2' => 'Pragma: no-cache',
          '3' => 'Content-Length: 340',
          '4' => 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8',
          '5' => 'Expires: -1',
          '6' => 'Server:microsoft-iis 7.5'
);

$contain = substr_count ( implode( $stack ), 'microsoft-iis 7.5' )?'string found':'string not found';

echo $contain;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate array and use [substr_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) to check that. It will return the number of times your search string occurs

```
foreach ($your_array as $values){
$occurrence = substr_count($values,'microsoft-iis 7.5') ? 'exists' : 'does not exist';
    echo $occurrence;
}
```